# Global variable through webapp (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've created a webapp using Spring MVC. I've set up internationalization through an interceptor in my dispatcher serlvet like this:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="lang" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="es" />
</bean>
```

Then I can access current locale in my controllers like this:

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()
```

Which is awesome, because I can then change my locale at any point and access current config anywhere.

Now I would like to do the same with some custom variables that behave in a similar fashion, in the sense that they slightly affect all of my app's behavior. (e.g. an "accesible" parameter indicates the app it should offer only accesible content).

I understand I can create my own interceptor to intercept any param named "accesible" like so:

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="com.myapp.MyInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="accesible" />
</bean>
```

But is there a way that I can access this value throughout my app like the LocaleContextHolder object does with locale? Can I make Spring inject it through a Cookie likeso?

Comment: Attributes stored in the Application scope are globals for the application.  This is JEE Application scope, but Spring provides a way to get it.

Comment: can you expand a little bit on your answer please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say throughout your app, do you mean the 'entire' app (like service, dao/repository) or just the web part of the app? Would a RequestContextHolder (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/RequestContextHolder.html) help your case? It has an option to retrieve currentRequestAttributes which is an implementation of RequestAttributes interface.

I have not tried it personally, but the RequestAttributes javadoc quotes "Supports access to request-scoped attributes as well as to session-scoped attributes, with the optional notion of a "global session"."

Comment: This looks like what I'm looking for, but how would you inject the parameter into this RequestContextHolder?

Comment: If you could tell us where you're getting this parameter from, it could help. But if the parameter is already in the http request, then you already have it in the context holder. Else, it might be possible to do it in a filter or an interceptor.